# restrict the "textfield" to accept only digits and maximum 10 digits in magento form

Tags: javascript, forms, contact-us

here is a code : http://pastebin.com/qCNGSKRn to display telephone filed to enter telephone number.

i want to restrict above field to accept only numbers and also maximum 10 numbers to be entered. all special charactars and special symbols and white spaces should not allowed.

that field should not accept more than 10 digits.

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class attribute add following class names

```
validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits
```

which will look like

```
class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>"
```

you can go through this link http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/ for more details about validation in magento

Comment: Which files contain the code for street address lines in checkout?